# Почему один и тот же SVG выглядит по разному?

Tags: svg

На странице ([ссылка](https://clusterfloor.ru/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0/#catalog__collection)) есть кнопка нарисованная в svg,она дважды повторяется на странице. Несмотря на то что код абсолютно идентичный, выглядят они по разному.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал простую html-страницу и вставил на нее тот же код и там он выглядит так как должен. Почему так происходит?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ширина / высота по-разному отображаются в инспекторе

Comment: @eri разве? у меня в обоих случаях 146 и 331 соответственно

Comment: не туда посмотрел. да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для второго `<svg` поменяйте `paint0_linear_1529_5346`, например, на `paint1_linear_1529_5347`

```
...
<picture>
  <source srcset="" type="image/webp">
    ...
    <path
      ...
      fill="#192239" stroke="url(#paint1_linear_1529_5347)"
      ...
      <linearGradient id="paint1_linear_1529_5347" x1="1.268" y1="104.16"
```

Comment: блин так все просто, что аж неловко. спасибо!